# How to get data from Firebase RealTimeDatabase using id

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a food ordering app and I have a list of CartItem

```
data class CartItemData(
  @PrimaryKey
  val cartItemId: String = UUID.randomUUID().mostSignificantBits.toString(),
  val userId: String,
  val foodId: String,
  val price: Double,
  val quantity: Int)
```

I want to retrieve food data from Firebase Realtime Database using the food ID in the cartItem and then display it to the user.

Here is my code to get food data from database

```
fun getFood(
    foodId: String,
    onGetFoodSuccess: (FoodData) -> Unit
) {
    foodsRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(foodId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.children.forEach { shot ->
                Log.d(TAG, shot.value.toString())
                val data = shot.getValue(FoodData::class.java)
                data?.let(onGetFoodSuccess)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }

    })
}
```

Here is my cart viewmodel

```
class CartViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val fireBaseRepository = FireBaseRepository.get()
  private val cartRepository = CartRepository.get()
  private val _cartState = MutableStateFlow(CartState())
  val cartState: StateFlow<CartState> = _cartState.asStateFlow()

  init {
      getCart()
  }

  fun getFood(
      foodId: String,
      onGetFoodSuccess: (FoodData) -> Unit
  ) {
      fireBaseRepository.getFood(
          foodId = foodId,
          onGetFoodSuccess = onGetFoodSuccess
      )
  }

  private fun getCart() {
      viewModelScope.launch {
          cartRepository.getCart().collect {cartItems ->
              _cartState.value = _cartState.value.copy(
                  cartItems = cartItems,
              )
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve data from the Realtime Database and pass it to my view after I have obtained the cart data from the SQLite database.

Comment: You've shared quite a lot of code, but no debugging information beyond that it doesn't work. I recommend debugging the code locally, and telling us the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: My getFood function works fine, and I don't have any problems with the Realtime Database. However, I don't know how to retrieve food data using a foodId and then display it to the user. I have a problem that a Composable function can't be called outside a composable function, so I can't create a view inside the getFood function after I have successfully retrieved the data. My question may not be clear since my English skills are not good.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I strong recommend you to check if the firebase is retrieving on snapshot properly, otherwise could be problem with your configuration.  Further, if at this point:

```
// code ...

foodsRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(foodId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.children.forEach { shot ->
                Log.d(TAG, shot.value.toString())
                val data = shot.getValue(FoodData::class.java)
                data?.let(onGetFoodSuccess)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }

    })

//code ...
```

This log is retrieving data, I could assume that the main problem is with this map:
`val data = shot.getValue(FoodData::class.java)`, probably you didn't hit that well,
and because of that this value is getting null and not calling the call back.  My suggestion is check the result of the snapshot from firebase and check if your data class `FoodData` is defined correctly, remind to set its default values, otherwise the app will crash.  check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data) for further explanations.

Now, if your problem is handle the callback to retrieves to the ui, is more simple.
You could just use cartState in the compose view and collect is as state for the composable, so every time that this stateFlow change its value the composable will be redrawed, check it out: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: My FoodData is defined correctly and my getFood function retrieves data correctly, and the data is not null. However, I tried to define a list of FoodData in cartState and update it when I successfully retrieve cartItemData, but my composable is not listening to the foodData update. It can receive the update with the cartItemData though.

Comment: Try to use a stateFlow like you've used for the _cartState , but now for the getFood.  and use it on the ui, like:
`
      fun getFood(
      foodId: String,
  ) {
      fireBaseRepository.getFood(
          foodId = foodId,
          onGetFoodSuccess = {
               _foodState.value = it
            }
      )
  }
`

Comment: It still doesn't work. My UI can't receive an update from FoodData. Additionally, I only declared a cartState variable to store the state of the CartScreen. I need foodData to display the name and image of the food since I only store the foodId in CartItem.

Comment: So you need a new state to the ui recompose and show the new data properly, I think yout are misunderstanding the composable state, you need update this state to update the compose with the new data.   You need call this method getFood and update the new state variable _foodState and use it in the screen that you want to use the FoodData, this should be enough.  Further , share your code of the screen that you are using the state variable.

Comment: But I think cartState is a state and every change of it will trigger the UI. I have write some state in this way and it working just fine, I only have a problem with this viewmodel. Additionally, please check my new question to see the code clearly since i don't provide cartState class in this question.

Comment: I'll repeat again, you didn't understand how the state works, think about it:
when you call the getFood() method the cartState will not be updated (because you aren't updating this state in this method), so how the ui could know that it need being updated?
Just pass a callback will not force the ui recompose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255921/discussion-between-pablo-and-habuiduc).